# Is it possible to allow only fingerprint authentication Webauthn in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, webauthn

I'm using Keycloak to implement the Webauthn authentication. Everything are working well. I just want to ask a question… Is it possible to allow only the fingerprint authentication method? I mean disable the usb key and any other options.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible as no known authenticators support the `uvm` extension which would be required for this.